# Why isn't the volume of a sphere $ π^2r^3?$

Tags: geometry, volume

[image]

Imagine two similiar circles. We rotate one on half of the other circumference. It gives a sphere with volume of $1/2(2πr) \cdot πr^2 = π^2r^3$

Comment: Can you explain why it should give that volume? I don't quite follow your reasoning.

Comment: you should intergrate this and get a volume for [sphere by revolution](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/VolumeWithRings.aspx)

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta The OP is multiplying the area of the rotating disc by the distance it was rotated.

Comment: See here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guldinus_theorem

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that the points closer to the center line of the circle don't move a distance of $2\pi r$ when the circle is rotated $2\pi$ radians. Rather a point at distance $h$ from the center line moves a distance of $2\pi h$. Now at distance $h$ the length of the rotating segment parallel to the center line is $2\sqrt{r^2 - h^2}$. Thus the volume is
$$\int_0^r 2\sqrt{r^2 - h^2} \cdot 2\pi h \, dh = \frac{4 \pi r^3}{3}.$$

Comment: Thanks but can anyone give me a clue why is it that arranging infinitesimally thin disks (aka circles) on a hemicircle doesn't give a full sphere?

Comment: @taratm: Your formula is assuming those disks are "flat": their top and bottom surfaces are parallel. If you try to arrange such disks to approximate a sphere, you will find either large gaps or large overlap. This introduces an error that does not tend to zero in the limit. Wedge shaped disks would avoid this, but of course they have a different volume (which may be hard to compute without already knowing the volume of a sphere).

Answer (score 5):

It is only the top of the semicircle that travels $2\pi$,  That gives a contribution to the volume of $2\pi$ times the area of the top.

Other parts of the semicircle - near the diameter - travel much shorter distances, so contribute smaller multiples of their area to the volume.

Answer (score 4):

For a more general view, any dimension, it turns out that the easy way to find the volume of higher dimensional spheres, including the one in $\mathbb R^3,$ is by adding two to the dimension and using polar coordinates. Given that the $n$-volume of the sphere of radius $R$ in $\mathbb R^n$ is
$$ \omega_n R^n,   $$ the easy calculation is that   the $(n+2)$-volume of the sphere of radius $R$ in $\mathbb R^{n+2}$ is
$$ \frac{2 \pi \omega_n}{n+2} R^{n+2},   $$ or
$$ \omega_{n+2} =  \frac{2 \pi \omega_n}{n+2}.  $$

Your example is $\omega_1 = 2,$ a segment of "radius" $1$ so length $2,$ so $\omega_3 =  \frac{2 \pi 2}{3} =  \frac{4 \pi }{3}.$

The odd ones are
$$ \omega_1 = 2, \; \omega_3 =   \frac{4 \pi }{3}, \;  \omega_5 =   \frac{8 \pi^2 }{15}, \ \omega_7 =   \frac{16 \pi^3 }{105},..., \; \omega_{2k +1} = \frac{ 2^{k+1} \; \; \pi^k}{(2k+1)!!}   $$

The even ones are
$$ \omega_2 = \pi, \; \omega_4 =   \frac{ \pi^2 }{2}, \;  \omega_6 =   \frac{ \pi^3 }{6}, ..., \; \omega_{2k} = \frac{\pi^k}{k!}  $$

Compare http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Closed_forms